# C++ Templated Classes Definition - Templated Return Type of Different Class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, templates

```
template <class T>
Row<T> Array2D<T>::operator[](int index) const
{

}
```

This code is not working, giving the error 'Declaration is incompatible with "Array2D::Row Array2D::operator[](int index) const" (declared at line 19". I'm using 2 templated classes, and I figure that that is the main issue but I'm not sure how it is fixed. Any help is appreciated, let me know if I need more details. Thanks.

Class Declaration:

```
#pragma once
#include "Array.h"
#include "Row.h"

template <class T>

class Array2D
{
template <class T> class Row;

public:
    Array2D();
    Array2D(int row, int col);
    Array2D(const Array2D & copy);

    ~Array2D();

    Array2D & operator =(const Array2D & rhs);
    Row<T> operator[](int index) const;

    int getRow() const;
    void setRow(int rows);
    int getColumns() const;
    void setColumns(int columns);

    T & Select(int row, int column);

private:
    Array<T> m_array;
    int m_row;
    int m_col;
};
```

Row Class:

```
#pragma once

#include "Array2D.h"

template <class T>

class Row
{
template <class T> class Array2D;

public:
    Row(Array2D<T> & array, int row);
    T & operator[](int column);

private:
    Array2D<T> & m_array2D;
    int m_row;

};

template <class T>
Row<T>::Row(Array2D<T> & array, int row)
{

}

template <class T>
T & Row<T>::operator[](int column)
{

}
```

Comment: Your shown code fails to meet all requirements for a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help]. The problem here is obvious - an obvious recursive header dependency. Unfortunately, due to the shown code's non-compliance with the requirements for a [mcve] it is not possible to show how it can be changed to resolve the circular dependency -- since any proposed answer has to make assumptions as what the missing code exactly is, which could be wrong, and waste everyone's time. Please read stackoverflow.com's [help], then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Problem was solved without any additional code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write

```
template <class T>
class Array2D
{
template <class T> class Row;

 // ...
};
```

you say that `Row` is a template class defined **inside** `Array2D`.

The same when you write

```
template <class T>
class Row
{
template <class T> class Array2D;

// ...
};
```

You saying that `Array2D` is a template class defined inside `Row`.

I suppose you intention declare `Raw` and `Array2D` as independent classes, so something as

```
template <class T>
class Row;

template <class T>
class Array2D
{
  // ...
};
```

and

```
template <class T>
class Array2D;

template <class T>
class Row
{    
  // ...
};
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you, hadn't had to use class declarations before so I was a bit confused.